# How to run multiple queries in the same jsp?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP that need to run multiple queries to send data in a csv to the database, but I'm not sure how to run the whole query. Single queries like `SELECT` works fine but I couldn't get the multi query to work.

My JSP:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix = "sql"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>CSV to DB</title>
</head>

<body>
<sql:setDataSource var = "snapshot" driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDb"
                   user = "root"  password = "1234"/>

<sql:query dataSource = "${snapshot}" var = "result">
    //Query here

</sql:query>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to run this query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Attendance.csv"
INTO TABLE `Attendance`
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`name`,`in-time`,`out-time`)
SET insert_date = CURRENT_DATE()
```

I tried to add `;` between each line but got an error.

The end result I'm trying to get is to have a `<input type = "file">` so a user uploads the csv and then that csv data is sent to the database (Was hoping to find a way to use that file in place of 
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Attendance.csv"`

Comment: Your so called query is for Oracle SQL Loader, right?

Comment: Using `LOAD DATA` like this with unsterilized input coming directly from the outside is probably not a good idea.  Instead, just let the user upload the file the usual way, and then process it internally.

Comment: @Codo Sorry, should have mentioned it. I ran it on MySQL using SQLylog.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that was what I wanted to do, but couldn't understand how it could work, so I thought of doing something simple first. Would really appreciate if you could share some tips

Comment: The `sql:query` tag requires an SQL statement returning a result set. In most cases, this is a SELECT statement. `LOAD DATA` doesn't return a result set. So it cannot be used in this context.

Comment: @Codo oh. anything else I can use in its place? edit : i tried `sql:update` but got the same error

Comment: The proper way is to do it in a Java class and once the operation is complete to display the result with a JSP page.

Comment: @Codo Im not sure where to start though :(

Comment: Implement a servlet. In the servlet, load the file into the database table. Then display the JSP page (`request.getRequestDispatcher("/loadingResult.jsp").forward(request, response);`). The servlet can also add data to the request (e.g. success flag, number of processed records) and the JSP page can display it.

Comment: @Codo I made it in java and managed to get it to work, but I dont know how to send it to my jsp. the code is : https://www.mycompiler.io/view/75C7Lg3 Can you help me with this? thank you for your time for the eariler stuff as well.

Comment: If I remember correctly you pass it in the servlet with `request.setAttribute("yourBean", data);` and retrieve it in JSP with `<jsp:useBean id="yourBean" class="DataClass" scope="request">`. The example assumes passing an object with getters and setters. You can also pass simple types such as a string but you might need to retrieve it with `getAttribute("data")`.